# Python - search and replace adjacent text in tab seperated text file

Tags: python, replace, csv

Trying to amend a text file, but an old part stays around and there is duplication. Original .txt file to change contains:

```
START_DATE           01/01/2014
START_TIME           02:00:00
REPORT_START_DATE    01/01/2014
REPORT_START_TIME    02:00:00
END_DATE             01/01/2014
END_TIME             03:00:00
```

I have used a txt file with a list to search for (START_DATE, START_TIME, REPORT_START_DATE, REPORT_START_TIME,END_DATE, END_TIME) and a second txt to replace the items. Although the code replaces the correct items, half the old values linger around, on a new line, and are not removed? There is also duplication due to the phrase START_TIME in REPORT_START_TIME. Any suggestions? I have been trying to amend the readlines(), to read().split('\n'), but nothing successful yet. So far the closest I can get from the code below is this:

```
START_DATE        02/02/2002
           01/01/2014
START_TIME        02:02:02
           02:00:00
REPORT_START_DATE 02/02/2002
        02/02/2002
    01/01/2014
REPORT_START_TIME 02:02:02
        02:02:02
    02:00:00
END_DATE        02/03/2002
             01/01/2014
END_TIME        03:03:03  
           03:00:00
```

Code thus far:

```
findlines = open('new_date_time_list.txt').read().split('\n')             
replacelines = open('new_date_time.txt').readlines()       
find_replace = dict(zip(findlines, replacelines))

with open('text_ammend.txt') as data:
    with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as new_data:
        for line in data:
            for key in find_replace:
                if key in line:
                    line = line.replace(key, find_replace[key])
            new_data.write(line)
```

Comment: Show us 1) the Python code you have tried, and 2) more input/output data.

Comment: Hi Lutz and Totem, sorry for not putting any code in, it's just that I have spent 2 days looking and read a lot on re, replace, line.replace with file.input etc, but the searches for a way to replace the adjacent text from a search have not yielded much.The best I can do it replace specific lines or texts. I will take your pointers, continue the searches, spend some more time on it and post my code again hopefully with a solution. I appreciate the pointers, was not looking for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't give you the code but the generic solution for this, each step contain key word just add python and search it in google or in here it's easy.

Or share with us your code please

Step :

```
#1 Open file and read it line by line
#2 Split each line in array, delimiter space
#3 If array lenght != 0 
##4 If array[0] == START_DATE
###4 array[1] = Your_new_date
###4 array[1] = Your_new_time
#5 Register and close the file
```